# can Static text or Text(dynamic) fields in jasper stretch across two pages?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating a pdf report which can be 4 - 5 pages long. I am using jasper studio to design the pdf document. I created A4 size document with 20px margin on each side. All i am using is detail bands, removed all other bands. detail band 1 holds page1 content , detail band2 holds page 2 and so on. Here are things i want to get clarification on.....

1. Is my approach correct? as i am using only detail bands to hold contents? Do
   you see any problem with excluding all other bands?
2. I am running into a problem of blank spaces: detail band1 holds page1,
   this band has height of 802px, Holds 3
       sections,Frame1(400 px) Frame2(300 px) and Frame3(192 px). In my
       case Frame2 has content that stretches dynamically depending on
       data. If Frame2 stretches to let say 350px, now i have only 52 px
       left in the first band, and my Frame3 is 192 px, as a result jasper
       is pushing this frame on to next page. Leaving 52px of Blank space
       on page 1 looks awkward. Is there a way i can configure jasper to show 
       52 px of frame 3 on page 1 and the rest 140 px on page 2, so that blank spaces are not shown in the pdf at any given time?

I tried playing with StretchType attribute on frame element and doesnt seem to help, does anyone have any input on this? thanks in advance.

sample jrxml that illustrates my problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.1  -->
<!-- 2017-03-24T14:43:38 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="newIAA" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="8de39cec-dd1f-418f-8ba0-9735f2f410ba">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="802">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="190" uuid="eb437bb0-bc94-43e5-8d78-a19c7b2a6b4e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="119" y="0" width="289" height="30" uuid="f2530fdd-884d-43cd-b504-f21e09c9db47">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                        <font size="22" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Customer Invoice ]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="80" width="553" height="110" uuid="565fea21-e609-4fae-abdb-640f7c2d322d">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement markup="styled">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" size="16"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[<b>Details : </b><br/><li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li><li>four</li>]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="190" width="555" height="120" uuid="a28f4d54-6499-4a69-b23f-caf5bbe7d126">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="555" height="190" uuid="5758f399-38cf-4f98-beda-ee25a9ae785f"/>
                    <textElement markup="styled"/>
                    <text><![CDATA[<b>Shipping Information </b><li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li><li>four</li><li>five</li><li>six</li><li>seven</li><li>eight</li><li>nine</li><li>ten</li><li>eleven</li><li>tweleve</li><li>thirteen</li><li>fourteen</li><li>fifteen</li>]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="440" width="555" height="280" uuid="ed31eefd-ccc2-419f-b29e-d1f33a855b6a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[<b>Address:</b><br/><li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li><li>four</li><li>five</li><li>six</li><li>seven</li><li>eight</li><li>nine</li><li>ten</li><li>eleven</li><li>tweleve</li><li>thirteen</li><li>fourteen</li><li>fifteen</li><li>sixteen</li><li>seventeen</li><li>eighteen</li><li>nineteen</li>]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Can you post your JRXML file?

Comment: How are you filling up Frame2? Is it some rows that you are pulling from a datasource?

Comment: added sample jrxml file. Yes in my real project Frame 2 is filled up with values coming from data source, some of the fields will stretch dynamically  as result frame2 size grows and thus pushing frame3 to next page and leaving empty space on page 1. In the jrxml i posted my problem is clearly demonstrated by Shipping information section, and empty space below it. if i reduce the size of Shipping information, Address section is printed on page 1. What i am really looking for is , instead of blank space , use that blank space to show part of address section and move the rest of it to next page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can a text field stretch across two pages?

The answer is YES, a *Text Field* element can stretch across two pages if you set its property **Stretch with overflow** to **TRUE**. I'm not sure about the *Static Text* element, though. I never had the need to. I tried a little bit playing around with a *Static Text* element but I didn't see an option that would make it stretch across two pages. Maybe, as its name implies, it's meant to be used with **static text**, something that is always the same, hence you know beforehand the size that it's going to occupy in the report, even though its place can change by other dynamic elements placed above it.

As far as excluding other bands is concerned, I don't see any problems with that, if you don't need them. However, depending on your data and the end result you want to achieve, it may help having other bands.

The **details** band works best with multiple row data sets. If you have a section that grows dynamically, I would suggest you put it inside a separate **details** band. Set the height of the band exactly as the height of the *Text Field* (enough to hold the text you are displaying), then it will dynamically span across as many pages as needed. Whenever you want something to be put on a separate page (unconditionally) you can add a **Break** element, and set the **Type** property to **Page**.

In your example I saw that you have put all the data inside a *Text Field*, which is not a good practice. If the data you are showing is fixed (when I say fixed I mean one row, not multiple rows), put each value in a separate *Text Field*, it won't leave a blank space in your first page. It will put, whatever can fit in, on the first page, and the rest will be moved onto the second page.

Here's your example, which I modified a little bit. Here, the address section spans across two pages.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.0  -->
<!-- 2017-03-26T14:03:51 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="newIAA" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="8de39cec-dd1f-418f-8ba0-9735f2f410ba">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <detail>
        <band height="197">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="190" uuid="eb437bb0-bc94-43e5-8d78-a19c7b2a6b4e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="119" y="0" width="289" height="30" uuid="f2530fdd-884d-43cd-b504-f21e09c9db47">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                        <font size="22" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[Customer Invoice ]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="80" width="553" height="110" uuid="565fea21-e609-4fae-abdb-640f7c2d322d">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement markup="styled">
                        <font fontName="SansSerif" size="16"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[<b>Details : </b><br/><li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li><li>four</li>]]></text>
                </staticText>
            </frame>
        </band>
        <band height="214">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="10" width="555" height="190" uuid="5758f399-38cf-4f98-beda-ee25a9ae785f"/>
                <textElement markup="styled"/>
                <text><![CDATA[<b>Shipping Information </b><li>one</li><li>two</li><li>three</li><li>four</li><li>five</li><li>six</li><li>seven</li><li>eight</li><li>nine</li><li>ten</li><li>eleven</li><li>tweleve</li><li>thirteen</li><li>fourteen</li><li>fifteen</li>]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
        <band height="470">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="10" width="555" height="20" uuid="462f317f-f89a-44ed-8e77-ad07a7b386e6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Address]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="30" width="555" height="20" uuid="64991fde-9a85-45f7-8061-8b418642e457">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[One]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="50" width="555" height="20" uuid="d5498a2b-1f41-4aa6-b0fd-82ca38f4fc75">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Two]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="70" width="555" height="20" uuid="92617678-99dc-489e-be27-d10ed00da863">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Three]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="90" width="555" height="20" uuid="e63ef22e-1f45-4841-b1c2-d17530ccde8c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Four]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="110" width="555" height="20" uuid="c355db54-18b6-4fce-9086-e9c0c02d94b6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Five]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="130" width="555" height="20" uuid="0b81eb8d-c240-4adf-acb8-882fab11666c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Six]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="150" width="555" height="20" uuid="e50850a3-a9b8-4320-a002-a8fcae766b81">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Seve]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="210" width="555" height="20" uuid="0ad5cd07-2e6a-4a28-90f6-3d12169b8f65">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Ten]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="270" width="555" height="20" uuid="e0dc3fab-9f99-4f75-a420-434562a942f5">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Thirteen]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="230" width="555" height="20" uuid="dafe0207-10f8-4a97-8f87-2774822d5bed">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Eleven]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="190" width="555" height="20" uuid="4d3d50c6-ace9-4b1c-8ed8-e66ad7d21b60">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nite]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="170" width="555" height="20" uuid="1f56f519-df14-438d-bd2b-3af7e6e6eaa0">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Eight]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="290" width="555" height="20" uuid="0dffe48d-65b8-4ce3-841f-9d9c85d69ad6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fourteen]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="250" width="555" height="20" uuid="09c6d28b-2eb1-401a-98ae-7aac905d54df">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Twelve]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="330" width="555" height="20" uuid="600b4b76-9244-4152-aa23-edd23c08d313">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fourteen]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="310" width="555" height="20" uuid="1d7ed52c-a57b-4e70-b645-f259087ec47a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Thirteen]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="350" width="555" height="20" uuid="da33f8f6-6269-4da3-9e86-b87037b1e543">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fourteen]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="410" width="555" height="20" uuid="5353b3a4-e9f4-4424-b054-b4158db1f4a8">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Thirteen]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="390" width="555" height="20" uuid="1e4c1aa6-1a9a-4764-a176-ebb498a99218">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fourteen]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="370" width="555" height="20" uuid="3f8c3dcd-e08d-40ee-8eae-afcfdfbbc14f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Thirteen]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="430" width="555" height="20" uuid="f7b1d764-97fa-45bd-99f1-2cd24e889709">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fourteen]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="450" width="555" height="20" uuid="9fadb409-fb15-41ed-9f39-ef6a7b86eaf5">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" markup="styled">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fourteen]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

I assume your *shipping information* is being pulled from a data source and that you are displaying it in *Text Field* elements. So, in this case, don't set the height of the band higher then a *Text Field* element. It will occupy just as much space as it needs.

---

**UPDATE:** *A minimal, complete and verifiable example*

To show how a *Text Field* spans across two pages I'm including a jasper report with dummy data. The text is embedded in the *Text Field*, but it woks the same way when the *Text Field* is populated by a data source.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.3.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.3.1  -->
<!-- 2017-03-28T08:17:44 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="012f65ad-c3b4-411c-81e1-947ff7200100">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="CRK_DATADAPTER.xml"/>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[usp_test]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Text" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="66" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="20" width="550" height="30" uuid="058b5b66-2862-4130-91a2-7e5817ac10fa"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font size="18" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Title]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="138" splitType="Stretch">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="550" height="130" uuid="9d0688b2-a0b4-4ae9-be83-dabc35a3321d"/>
                <textElement markup="html"/>
                <text><![CDATA[Some text goes here:
<li>ka hsdlfkashdfkashdfkasjd fhkashdf </li>
<li>ka hsdlfkashdfkashdfkasjd fhkashdf </li>
<li>ka hsdlfkashdfkashdfkasjd fhkashdf </li>
<li>ka hsdlfkashdfkashdfkasjd fhkashdf </li>
<li>ka hsdlfkashdfkashdfkasjd fhkashdf </li>
<li>ka hsdlfkashdfkashdfkasjd fhkashdf </li>
<li>ka hsdlfkashdfkashdfkasjd fhkashdf </li>
<li>ka hsdlfkashdfkashdfkasjd fhkashdf </li>
<li>ka hsdlfkashdfkashdfkasjd fhkashdf </li>]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
        <band height="20">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="450" height="20" uuid="7fd5b2f7-5044-465b-b2c3-a68a8263eb7a"/>
                <textElement markup="html"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, insolens tincidunt ea vix. In eos minim detraxit, nibh expetenda pro ex. Iudicabit patrioque mel in. Sumo eligendi eloquentiam eam ei. Iisque bonorum meliore eum te, no viris conceptam his, eu nulla tation fabellas eos. Sea verear laoreet no.<br>Id odio dicant ius, tritani erroribus cum ne. Pri nominavi copiosae eu, est eirmod aliquando moderatius ut, latine commodo labitur ut duo. Dicit dicunt nonumes his te, solet graecis pertinacia ius cu. Mea ne modo deseruisse. Iriure commune tacimates ne sea, qui explicari definitiones cu. Eu salutandi appellantur consequuntur mei, nec te dico nemore.<br>Qui et utamur tacimates honestatis, sea iuvaret fabellas percipitur cu, no vim autem recteque. Vis fugit mundi convenire et, ut sed doming epicuri salutatus. No eius idque ponderum nec. Cum fugit facete ut, an vero saepe inciderint mel.<br>Viris nemore ei nam, qui graece recteque id, nam vero elit ridens ea. Labitur placerat mnesarchum ius an, ad est sonet nonumes. Dicit dicunt labitur nam id, corrumpit torquatos ei nec. Affert consetetur mediocritatem ne nam, inani efficiantur cu duo, civibus contentiones eos et.<br>Definiebas vituperata vis cu, unum fierent an cum. Et enim elitr cum, ex hinc aperiri has, sea in maiorum tibique. Cum iudico detracto cu, choro veniam consul vim et. Qui graeco commodo in, per at eirmod omittam, ut pro sale placerat.<br>Iudico forensibus his ut, no eros facete qualisque qui. Ne dolor facilisis complectitur ius, at cum sale etiam pertinacia, his regione dolorum cu. Ea sale facer usu, wisi paulo simul at duo, tritani dolorum urbanitas et eam. Liber blandit inciderint has cu. Usu an quodsi tibique interesset, at nam movet latine periculis. Mollis copiosae efficiantur vix no, te sit idque accumsan. Pro illud error saepe id, ius ut meliore inermis.<br>Sed ne quaeque aliquam inciderint, an utroque lucilius intellegam per, ius aperiri nonumes adipiscing ea. Vidit virtute his at, cu sit constituam definitionem concludaturque. Fugit fastidii liberavisse per cu. Vim suas omnium ei, et inani sadipscing mel, vis ei expetenda molestiae definiebas.<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, insolens tincidunt ea vix. In eos minim detraxit, nibh expetenda pro ex. Iudicabit patrioque mel in. Sumo eligendi eloquentiam eam ei. Iisque bonorum meliore eum te, no viris conceptam his, eu nulla tation fabellas eos. Sea verear laoreet no.<br>Id odio dicant ius, tritani erroribus cum ne. Pri nominavi copiosae eu, est eirmod aliquando moderatius ut, latine commodo labitur ut duo. Dicit dicunt nonumes his te, solet graecis pertinacia ius cu. Mea ne modo deseruisse. Iriure commune tacimates ne sea, qui explicari definitiones cu. Eu salutandi appellantur consequuntur mei, nec te dico nemore.<br>Qui et utamur tacimates honestatis, sea iuvaret fabellas percipitur cu, no vim autem recteque. Vis fugit mundi convenire et, ut sed doming epicuri salutatus. No eius idque ponderum nec. Cum fugit facete ut, an vero saepe inciderint mel."]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="21b54d29-9d8c-4c3a-82bb-f2aeb2256941">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Text]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
        <band height="20">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="-5" y="0" width="550" height="20" uuid="cff4e917-c84e-42a6-ae07-5aa19ae0b70f">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement markup="html"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, insolens tincidunt ea vix. In eos minim detraxit, nibh expetenda pro ex. Iudicabit patrioque mel in. Sumo eligendi eloquentiam eam ei. Iisque bonorum meliore eum te, no viris conceptam his, eu nulla tation fabellas eos. Sea verear laoreet no.<br>Id odio dicant ius, tritani erroribus cum ne. Pri nominavi copiosae eu, est eirmod aliquando moderatius ut, latine commodo labitur ut duo. Dicit dicunt nonumes his te, solet graecis pertinacia ius cu. Mea ne modo deseruisse. Iriure commune tacimates ne sea, qui explicari definitiones cu. Eu salutandi appellantur consequuntur mei, nec te dico nemore.<br>Qui et utamur tacimates honestatis, sea iuvaret fabellas percipitur cu, no vim autem recteque. Vis fugit mundi convenire et, ut sed doming epicuri salutatus. No eius idque ponderum nec. Cum fugit facete ut, an vero saepe inciderint mel.<br>Viris nemore ei nam, qui graece recteque id, nam vero elit ridens ea. Labitur placerat mnesarchum ius an, ad est sonet nonumes. Dicit dicunt labitur nam id, corrumpit torquatos ei nec. Affert consetetur mediocritatem ne nam, inani efficiantur cu duo, civibus contentiones eos et.<br>Definiebas vituperata vis cu, unum fierent an cum. Et enim elitr cum, ex hinc aperiri has, sea in maiorum tibique. Cum iudico detracto cu, choro veniam consul vim et. Qui graeco commodo in, per at eirmod omittam, ut pro sale placerat.<br>Iudico forensibus his ut, no eros facete qualisque qui. Ne dolor facilisis complectitur ius, at cum sale etiam pertinacia, his regione dolorum cu. Ea sale facer usu, wisi paulo simul at duo, tritani dolorum urbanitas et eam. Liber blandit inciderint has cu. Usu an quodsi tibique interesset, at nam movet latine periculis. Mollis copiosae efficiantur vix no, te sit idque accumsan. Pro illud error saepe id, ius ut meliore inermis.<br>Sed ne quaeque aliquam inciderint, an utroque lucilius intellegam per, ius aperiri nonumes adipiscing ea. Vidit virtute his at, cu sit constituam definitionem concludaturque. Fugit fastidii liberavisse per cu. Vim suas omnium ei, et inani sadipscing mel, vis ei expetenda molestiae definiebas.<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, insolens tincidunt ea vix. In eos minim detraxit, nibh expetenda pro ex. Iudicabit patrioque mel in. Sumo eligendi eloquentiam eam ei. Iisque bonorum meliore eum te, no viris conceptam his, eu nulla tation fabellas eos. Sea verear laoreet no.<br>Id odio dicant ius, tritani erroribus cum ne. Pri nominavi copiosae eu, est eirmod aliquando moderatius ut, latine commodo labitur ut duo. Dicit dicunt nonumes his te, solet graecis pertinacia ius cu. Mea ne modo deseruisse. Iriure commune tacimates ne sea, qui explicari definitiones cu. Eu salutandi appellantur consequuntur mei, nec te dico nemore.<br>Qui et utamur tacimates honestatis, sea iuvaret fabellas percipitur cu, no vim autem recteque. Vis fugit mundi convenire et, ut sed doming epicuri salutatus. No eius idque ponderum nec. Cum fugit facete ut, an vero saepe inciderint mel."]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: thanks very much for your response. In paragraph 4 of your response "In your example I saw that you have put all the data inside a Text Field, which is not a good practice.". I assume you were talking about static text field, the reason i did it that way is in my real project the text is "terms and conditions" nearly 50 to 60 lines, which is clearly multiple lines. I did not want to post my actual jrxml source, so i made up above example. So what you are saying is, if i use Text field(Stretch with overflow to TRUE) and fill it with data source dynamically, it should work as expected?

Comment: Ah yeah, you are right. I didn't think of such a use case. Anyway, it should work as expected. I have updated the answer to include an example that you can play with.

Comment: I put all 60 lines of terms and conditions in TextField with Stretch with overflow to TRUE, and it stretches across two pages without leaving blank spaces(i accepted your answer). But at the end of the text field it is creating roughly 40px of empty space before next report element. any idea why it is doing that?

Comment: There could be many reasons, check the _Spacing Before_ and _Spacing After_, _Line Spacing Size_, distance between elements, band height, the text that is displayed in the _Text Field_ (it may contain **newline** characters in the end), etc.

Comment: It was overlapping with previous report element, fixed it. works fine now, thanks for your help.

Comment: How to do the same auto adjust for element width?